# [Ajax][PHP] - login form, response is always empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, authentication

I have a problem with my login form. Every time when i write (correct or incorrect) login and password in my login form, my JS script return error and when i try to print "response" it is empty.
 Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val().trim();
    var paw = $("#paw").val().trim();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'check.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {name:name, paw:paw},
      success: function(response){
        if(response == 1){
          window.location= "home.php";
        }
        else{
          alert("error");
        }
      }
    });


  });
});
```

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name = trim($_POST['name']);
  $paw1 = trim($_POST['paw']);
  $paw = md5($paw1);
  try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE login=:nazwa and haslo=:has");
    $stmt->execute(array(':nazwa'=>$name, ':has'=>$paw));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row['haslo']==$paw){
      echo 1;
      $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['login'];
    }
    else {

      echo 0;
    }
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` line. The reason is that the button key value is not sent via the AJAX call. To verify, do a `print_r($_POST);`

instead verify that name and password variables are not `empty()`

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['paw'])) {

}
```

Also do not use `md5()` for your passwords. use php's `password_hash()` to hash and `password_verify()` to verify that the posted password via the form matches the hash stored in the database for that user.